# How to run if/else statement to check if XML node is empty?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, if-statement

My question today deals with checking an XML file for a specific node.

Example:

```
<vid 
flv="videoName" 
thumb="thumbnail.jpg"
title="Video Title" 
logo="Path to logo here">
</vid>

<vid 
flv="videoName" 
thumb="thumbnail.jpg"
title="Video Title" 
</vid>
```

The first vid node contains a path to a logo graphic, I then need to check in my ActionScript if there is a logo there or not, and to do something if there is(display the logo)

Now below is the code I need help with, I can trace out the logo path so I thought I could run a simple if/else to check if there is anything in that node and if so to do something:

```
private function thumbOver(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
trace("\r");
trace("YOU ROLLED OVER THUMBNAIL: " + e.target.id);
trace("PLAY THIS VIDEO: " + tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@flv);
trace("THE VIDEO TITLE: " + tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@title);
trace("HAS LOGO? " + tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@logo);

if (tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@logo == null)
{
    trace("No logo here");
            // Don't do anything
} else {
    trace("Does have Logo");
            // Code to display Logo
}

    /*var lgo:Bitmap = loader.getBitmap(tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@logo);
    lgo.width  = 78;
    lgo.height = 44;
    lgo.x = 0;

    logoPlace.addChild(lgo);
    thumbRollmc.addChild(logoPlace);*/

descriptionMaker(tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@title);
}
```

Now I've tried everything, but it will always trace out "Does have a logo" no matter what I do. I tried:

```
 if (tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@logo == "")

 if (tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].@logo == null)
```

However I get the same results, what should my approach to this problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tabData[tabID].video[e.target.id].hasOwnProperty("@logo"))
```

Comment: OMG thanks that was it! :D I'm not that well verse with all the XML syntax... I love this site!

Comment: hasOwnProperty is a method of the Flash Object class, so you can use that on pretty much any class. Very handy.